# Python: ignoring input from users

Tags: python, python-2.7, math

This is a math game I am adding to a chat messenger. A math question is asked every 60 seconds. The users have that 60 seconds to answer the question before a new question is asked.

**def askQuestion()** provides the question.

**def checkAnswer(msg, name)** checks if the message typed by the user is the correct answer to the question and then says who got the correct answer.

The issue is that more than one user is able to answer the question. How can I make it so that once one of the users puts the correct answer any other user that puts the correct answer is ignored?

**I am new to coding and am using Python 2.7.**

```py
def askQuestion():
    if question == 'add':
        a = randrange(100, 999)
        b = randrange(10, 99)
        question = 'What is ' + str(a) + ' + ' + str(b) + '?'
        correctAnswer = str(a + b)
    elif question == 'multiply':
        a = randrange(100, 999)
        availableB = [0, 1, 10, 5]
        b = availableB[randrange(4)]
        question = 'What is ' + str(a) + ' x ' + str(b) + '?'
        correctAnswer = str(a * b)
    print(question)

Timer(60 * 1000, askQuestion, repeat=True, timeType='real')

def checkAnswer(msg, name):
    if msg.lower() == correctAnswer:
        print(name + ' got the correct answer!')
```

Comment: Why are you using Python 2.7? it reached EOF a year and a half ago.

Comment: The chat messenger is using Python 2.7.

Comment: Hi! Welcome to StackOverflow. There is something we really like and that we call "Minimal Reproducible Example". Your code is not reproducible, because we don't know what `Internal._chatMessage` is. Of course we guess how it is supposed to work, but we can't execute it on our own computer. It would have been preferable to simplify your code so that it is more focused on the exact problem you want to solve and less focused on all the context. See also: [Minimal Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: Sorry, I just edited the code to reflect a better Minimal Reproducible Example.

Comment: Just a side comment - since the correct answer is always a number, using `msg.lower()` before comparing with `correctAnswer` is not particularly useful. Instead I suggest using `msg.strip()`, which will remove whitespace before and after the answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This works! Thank you all for your help!

```py
correctAnswer = None
answeredBy = None

def askQuestion():
    global answeredBy
    global correctAnswer
    if question == 'add':
        a = randrange(100, 999)
        b = randrange(10, 99)
        question = 'What is ' + str(a) + ' + ' + str(b) + '?'
        correctAnswer = str(a + b)
    elif question == 'multiply':
        a = randrange(100, 999)
        availableB = [0, 1, 10, 5]
        b = availableB[randrange(4)]
        question = 'What is ' + str(a) + ' x ' + str(b) + '?'
        correctAnswer = str(a * b)
    print(question)
    answeredBy = None
    return

Timer(60 * 1000, askQuestion, repeat=True, timeType='real')

def checkAnswer(msg, name):
    if answeredBy is not None:
        print(answeredBy + ' already got the correct answer!')
        return
    if msg.lower() == correctAnswer:
        print(name + ' got the correct answer!')
        return
```

Answer (score 0):

The best solution is probably not to modify `checkAnswer`, but rather to modify the part of the code which calls `checkAnswer` when a user posts a message.

However, you did not provide that part of the code.

A possible solution is to add a "state" variable to `checkAnswer`, with a persistent value which is kept between calls; this variable will tell `checkAnswer` whether it's currently accepting answers or not.

I will call this variable `checkAnswer.alreadyAnswered`; it is set to `False` every time a new question is asked, and set to `True` every time a correct answer is given.

```py
def checkAnswer(msg, name):
    if not checkAnswer.alreadyAnswered:
        if msg.lower() == correctAnswer:
            checkAnswer.alreadyAnswered = True
            Internal._chatMessage(name + " got the correct answer!")
checkAnswer.alreadyAnswered = False

def askQuestion():
    if question == 'add':
        a = randrange(100, 999)
        b = randrange(10, 99)
        question = 'What is ' + str(a) + ' + ' + str(b) + '?'
        correctAnswer = str(a + b)
    elif question == 'multiply':
        a = randrange(100, 999)
        availableB = [0, 1, 10, 5]
        b = availableB[randrange(4)]
        question = 'What is ' + str(a) + ' x ' + str(b) + '?'
        correctAnswer = str(a * b)
    checkAnswer.alreadyAnswered = False
    Internal._chatMessage(question)

Timer(60 * 1000, askQuestion, repeat=True, timeType='real')
```

Answer (score 0):

**use timeout like this:**

```
 
 
# Event object used to send signals from one thread to another
stop_event = Event()
 
 
def do_actions():
    i = 0
    while True:
        i += 1
        Timer(60 * 1000, askQuestion, repeat=True, timeType='real')
 
        # Here we make the check if the other thread sent a signal to stop execution.
        if stop_event.is_set():
            break
 
 
if __name__ == '__main__':
    # We create another Thread
    action_thread = Thread(target=do_actions)
 
    # Here we start the thread and we wait 5 seconds before the code continues to execute.
    action_thread.start()
    action_thread.join(timeout=5)
 
    # We send a signal that the other thread should stop.
    stop_event.set()
```